# Cannot change registry permission

Tags: permissions, windows-registry

I cannot change permissions in the registry even from an Administrator account. Can anybody tell me how I can do this? See below all is grayed out.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is greyed out because the permissions are inherited from the parent key. **In order to get access to these options, you will need to break inheritance on this object.**

To do that, in the *Advanced Security Settings* window, click the *Disable inheritance* button.

[image: Advanced Security Settings]

Then click *Convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object.*

[image: Block inheritance]